# How to find instrumental response for a seismic station

Tags: seismology, instrumentation

I received seismic data for which I would like to remove the instrumental response. The only information I have is that they were recorded on a Trillium broadband seismometer with a cutoff period of 40s.

I assumed it referred to the trillium 40 for which I found the following [user guide](https://www.passcal.nmt.edu/webfm_send/948). Some information is given about poles and zeros at pages 40-41 but it is unclear to me which one I should use. Besides, I intend to manually define them using [Obspy](https://docs.obspy.org/tutorial/code_snippets/frequency_response.html) but I am not entirely sure of how to do it.

At this point, I was planning to copy [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071620/python-how-to-transform-counts-in-to-m-s-using-the-obspy-module).